# What is maximum file size to upload via Dropbox API v2?

Tags: dropbox-api, http-status-code-413

I am trying to upload files to Dropbox using API v2 /upload endpoint. Sometimes I get a 413 error response from the Dropbox server (Request entity too large).

Unfortunately, maximum file size is not described in the documentation, maybe someone know about it?

Comment: They have mentioned the upload limit, check this out https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, we'll add this to the documentation.

I'm pretty sure the limit is unchanged from API v1, so it's 150MB. Beyond that, you should use [`/upload/session/*`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-files-upload_session-start).